# Unity Collisions - isKinematic Allows Objects to Go Through

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision, rigid-bodies

I have a user navigating and colliding with a rigid body. I would like one object to slide along the other when the collision happens. It behaves this way when the isKinematic setting is NOT checked. However, the object then moves. I would like the object to stay in place when collided with. When I turn isKinematic off, the user is able to navigate through the rigid body which shouldn't happen. Any ideas on how to fix this?

As of now, I don't have any scripts associated with the rigid body.

Comment: [When `isKinematic` is checked, forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore.](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If one object is moving and the other should be static:

- RigidBody + Collider for **the moving object**
- RigidBody (isKinematic) + Collider for **the static object**

So basically you are missing the Colliders to avoid GameObjects go through each other

Comment: I tried using those settings but I'm running into an issue with the moving object. I got an error that Unity no longer supports non-convex mesh colliders with non-kinematic rigid bodies. When I made the mesh collider convex, the object falls through space. I want the object to move only when initiated by the user.

Comment: but what type of collider are you using? what is the shape of the object you want to move?

Comment: One has a mesh collider and one has a capsule collider. The first is a square-like shape and the second a capsule.

Comment: You should change the mesh collider for something else in the moving Object. Try a shape which covers most of the GameObject but at the same time is a primitive, like another capsule, a rectangle... basically something not very demanding for the engine

Comment: That solved that issue; however, I'm still having the problem that when I add a rigidBody, the object is falling without being navigated by the user. I have the Gravity turned off. When I check isKinematic, the object doesn't fall anymore. However, I have the same issue with choosing between the object moving or being able to go through the object.

Comment: well you need to add a ground in the scene. Also with a collider, so the object you are moving moves over that ground and it doesnt fall down. Not sure if this is what you mean with falling

Comment: Use a cube for example, and change its scale to make it flat in one axis and quite long in the other two ( in x and z)

Comment: I don't want the object to sit on the ground though. I'd like it to be able to float in space whenever the user leaves it.

Comment: Ok so if you want to have a GameObject which moves controlled by the player and doesnt fall you need to deactivate Use Gravity, so it will not fall down. I will summarize all and update the answer. And please, it my help was useful for you, I would appreciate if you accept my answer

Comment: I did deactivate use gravity but it still fell! And I would be more than happy to accept your answer. I'm new to this though, how do I do that? Sorry :-)

Comment: it still fall down even with gravity deactivated when you press play?

Comment: Corrrct, it falls even without gravity. But it doesn't fall when I check isKinematic but then I have the same issue I started with.

Comment: ok, Im missing something, let me test a few things and I will come back, hopefully with the final solution

Comment: Well you can start by trying this, assuming you are doing some kind of space game, where there is no gravity for any GameObject in the scene. You have to: Edit -> Project Settings -> Physics, and in the window that will open, in the first field called Gravity, change the value -9.81 for 0

Comment: I'm having the same issue even after changing the gravity.

Comment: Even after changing gravity objects fall down? Ok this afternoon I will try to recreate all. But I recommend you to write this as a new post. I mean a question about why gameObjects fall down even when you disable use gravity and the Physics gravity, maybe someone else come up with something I am missing. If you make this question, add details and add images of the inspector, people will participate more when they have more information about eveyrthing you have tried so far.